# Реализация чата на rxjava+retrofit

Tags: java, android

Сервер при запросе возвращает `json` схему чата(дата, время, id пользователя, его сообщение и т.д), c помощью `retrofit` я создал метод запроса чата.
Вопрос, как с помощью `rxjava` реализовать отправку запроса на сервер скажем раз в x секунд? И вообще как вам такая архитектура чата? Мб лучше было бы через сокеты реализовать? Нужно ли использовать ORM при реализации чата?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно чат нужно через сокеты. Вы такими периодическими запросами весь заряд батареи в фоне скушаете.

При чем тут ORM? Если Вы храните сообщения в базе, то тут уже выбор за Вами, использовать для доступа к базе ORM или руками писать все необходимое.

Я бы конечно использовал, но и без ORM надо уметь творить.